# In react project when i try to use npm start command getting error

Tags: reactjs, npm

Here is my react project error for your info

npm start

> react-sidebar-v1@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
Name: index.html
Searched in: D:\react\react-sidebar-v1\public

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1woe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the public folder in  `D:\react\react-sidebar-v1`  not in `D:\react\react-sidebar-v1\src`